# AngularJS update output of ngRepeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table and with ngRepeat I am showing the products and details

I also have a directive

```
.directive('onFinishRenderFilters', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    }
})
```

that I use to fix the html css style

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function (ngRepeatFinished) {

if($(".row0_fixed").outerHeight()>($(".row0").outerHeight())){
  $(".row0").outerHeight($(".row0_fixed").outerHeight());
}else{
  $(".row0_fixed").outerHeight($(".row0").outerHeight());
}

if($(".row1_fixed").outerHeight()>($(".row1").outerHeight())){
  $(".row1").outerHeight($(".row1_fixed").outerHeight());
}else{
  $(".row1_fixed").outerHeight($(".row1").outerHeight());
}

if($(".row2_fixed").outerHeight()>($(".row2").outerHeight())){
  $(".row2").outerHeight($(".row2_fixed").outerHeight());
}else{
  $(".row2_fixed").outerHeight($(".row2").outerHeight());
}

if($(".row3_fixed").outerHeight()>($(".row3").outerHeight())){
  $(".row3").outerHeight($(".row3_fixed").outerHeight());
}else{
  $(".row3_fixed").outerHeight($(".row3").outerHeight());
}

if($(".row4_fixed").outerHeight()>($(".row4").outerHeight())){
  $(".row4").outerHeight($(".row4_fixed").outerHeight());
}else{
  $(".row4_fixed").outerHeight($(".row4").outerHeight());
}

if($(".row5_fixed").outerHeight()>($(".row5").outerHeight())){
  $(".row5").outerHeight($(".row5_fixed").outerHeight());
}else{
  $(".row5_fixed").outerHeight($(".row5").outerHeight());
}

if($(".row6_fixed").outerHeight()>($(".row6").outerHeight())){
  $(".row6").outerHeight($(".row6_fixed").outerHeight());
}else{
  $(".row6_fixed").outerHeight($(".row6").outerHeight());
}

if($(".row7_fixed").outerHeight()>($(".row7").outerHeight())){
  $(".row7").outerHeight($(".row7_fixed").outerHeight());
}else{
  $(".row7_fixed").outerHeight($(".row7").outerHeight());
}

if($(".row8_fixed").outerHeight()>($(".row8").outerHeight())){
  $(".row8").outerHeight($(".row8_fixed").outerHeight());
}else{
  $(".row8_fixed").outerHeight($(".row8").outerHeight());
}

if($(".row9_fixed").outerHeight()>($(".row9").outerHeight())){
  $(".row9").outerHeight($(".row9_fixed").outerHeight());
}else{
  $(".row9_fixed").outerHeight($(".row9").outerHeight());
}
});
}])
```

The problem is if I delete a product from the scope, the directive doesn't run again, and the style is broken

Thanks in advance

Comment: _if I delete a product from the scope, the directive doesn't run again_ That's the beauty of ngRepeat ;)

Comment: What is the end result you want?

Comment: thank you @jacob, I just want to adjust the outerHeight again of the rows, but I don't realize how I can do that.

Comment: not to be a jerk, but that's not an end result. ex "I want the last row of the table to be 1.5x the height of the other rows."

Comment: I have dynamic content inside the table, so what I need is to run a piece of code to fix the table, as the content is dynamic, I can't have a fixed size. I need to run the code that I have on the question to fix the table.

Comment: That's not _what_, that's _how_. The question you're asking is probably not the one you should be asking, but to answer it: you can set up a [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) on your model (to watch for changes and invoke your formatting function when that happens).

Comment: I now realize, I want to be able to know when the view finish rendering. Thank you @jacob, I will try to do it with the $watch.

Comment: thank you @jacob with your help I was able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a $watch to the $scope and with jquery see if the outerHeight is changing and fixit

here is part of the code I used to fix the problem

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
   return $(".row0").outerHeight();
},function(){
  fixTable();
});
```